# Send continuous data from 4G module to server

Tags: php, server, gsm, continuous, 4g

I have the Telit LE910 4G LTE module connected to a Teensy board (Arduino will do). While I am able to send data to my PHP server using HTTP requests (POST and GET), I am not able to send continuous data due to necessary delays for the server to respond back:

```
  [...]
  // SOCKET DIAL
  LTESerial.print("AT#SD=1,0,80,\"SERVER IP\"\r\n");
  delay(5000);

  // POST
  LTESerial.print("POST /server/index.php?data=");
  LTESerial.print(random(1000));
  LTESerial.print(" HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  LTESerial.print("Host: SERVER IP\r\n\r\n");  
  delay(5000);
  while (getResponse() > 0);
```

This is simply an example (written here), but it somewhat illustrates what I am doing. The above code is supposed to be put inside a while loop, so that once the data is uploaded to a .txt file on the server, the module reconnects to the server and POST another data point.

Obviously, I want to avoid these delays and parse data to the server as fast as possible (as soon as the data is available). This is why I opted for the 4G LTE version.

Tweaking the delays might give me an extra second or so, but my project includes plotting a lot of data points in "real time", so it is very time sensitive.

Any idea on how to send a continuous data stream to the server on 4G? I am thinking about buffering some data points and use FTP to upload the data, but I assume uploading files to the server might even take more time than now.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your use case might be better suited to a special IoT (internet of things) protocol rather than a more client server connection orientated protocol, like HTTP.

There are several protocols in use in the IoT world but some of the most common are:

- MQTT - http://mqtt.org
- COAP - http://coap.technology
- XMPP - https://xmpp.org

These should not only address your latency concerns but are generally also designed to minimise data overhead and processing/battery use also.

You should be able to find PHP examples for these also - for example one for MQTT:

- https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-php.html

Comment: I would like to keep using HTTP, due to limitation. In any case, I have complete access to the private server on WAMP, meaning I should be able to start a 'socket listener', direct the 4G module to this listener and stream data endlessly. I tried this using PHP, but I still experience these delays. Is there any way to keep the socket dial alive and keep sending POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat got it to work using some of the existing code above, but it is still not optimal. This might be useful for others.

This is what I did:

1) I socket dial only once (during initialization)

2) The POST-section is running inside a loop infinitely. The 5 second delay is now reduced to 200 ms and I added some headers, like so:

```
  //unsigned long data = random(1000000000000000, 9999999999999999);
  LTESerial.print("POST /index.php?data=");
  LTESerial.print(data);
  LTESerial.print(" HTTP/1.1\r\n");
  LTESerial.print("Host: ADDRESS\r\n");
  LTESerial.print("Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
  delay(200);
  while (getResponse() > 0);
```

3) Turns out my WAMP server (PHP) had limitations as default in terms of maximum HTTP requests, timeouts and the like. I had to increase these numbers (I changed them to unlimited) inside `php.ini`.

However, while I am able to "continuously" send data to my server, a delay of 200 ms is still a lot. I would like to see something close to serial communication, if possible.

Also, when looking at the serial monitor, I get:

```
[...]
408295030
4238727231
3091191349
2815507344

----------->(THEN SUDDENLY)<------------

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 02 Jun 2

2900442411

016 19:29:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) PHP/5.6.15
X-P16

3817418772

Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: te

86026031

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 02 Jun 2016 19:29:4

3139838298
75272508
[...]

----------->(After 330 iterations/POSTs, I get)<------------

NO CARRIER
NO CARRIER
NO CARRIER
NO CARRIER
```

So my question is:
1) How do I eliminate the 200 ms delay as well?

2) If my data-points have different sizes, the delay will have to change as well. How to do this dynamically?

3) Why does it stop at 330-ish iterations? This doesn't happen if data is only 4 digits.

4) Why do I suddenly get responses from the server?

I hope someone can use this for their own project, however this does not suffice for mine. Any ideas?